# Updating XML Files inside a directory

Tags: c#, .net, xml, loops, foreach

I'm still kind of new to C# but I created a utility where if for whatever reason their IP address were to change or they want to change it, the IP address that was stored will update to the current IP address.

My code is supposed to be filtering all the xml config files within the directory and updating it with a new IP address. However their are some xml config files in certain folders that I DON'T want to change like the ones that say net.tcp://localhost.

```
<endpoint name="SessionLocal" address="net.tcp://localhost:7732/AuthenticationServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Stuff.Services.ServiceContracts.IAuthenticationService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehaviorName">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint name="DataLocal" address="net.tcp://localhost:7732/DataServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Stuff.Services.ServiceContracts.IDataService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehaviorName">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
```

The next couple folders contain xml files that I WANT to change have actual IP addresses like

```
<endpoint name="SubscriptionLocal" address="net.tcp://10.249.30.4:7732/EventSubscriberServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Stuff.Services.ServiceContracts.ISubscriptionService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint name="PublishLocal" address="net.tcp://10.249.30.4:7732/EventPublishServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Stuff.Services.ServiceContracts.IPublishService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
```

1) How would I add code so that user will have the option to either manually type in an IPaddress that will update the Ipaddress within the the xml config file. (IF the endpoint address within xml config file does not have an address of localhost)

2) How would I write code inside the else statement to continue the enumeration within the directory?

[image]

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dir = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Stuff\Noodles");
        foreach (var folder in dir)
        {
            var path = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string newIPAddress = "10.246.31.4";
            foreach (var xmlfile in path)
            {
                var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
                var endpointsToUpdate = doc
                    .Descendants("endpoint")
                    .Where(x => new Uri((string)x.Attribute("address")).Host != "localhost")
                    .ToArray();

                // skip if there is nothing to update
                //if (!endpointsToUpdate.Any()) return;
                if (endpointsToUpdate.Any());
                {

                    foreach (var endpoint in endpointsToUpdate)
                    {
                        string address = (string)endpoint.Attribute("address");
                        string pattern = "//\\d[^:]+";
                        address = Regex.Replace(address, pattern, "//" + newIPAddress);

                        endpoint.Attribute("address").SetValue(address);
                    }
                    else 
                    {

                    }

                    doc.Save(xmlfile);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I recognized my code from previous posting.  Try :            XElement[] endpointsToUpdate = doc
             .Descendants("endpoint")
             .Where(x => (string)x.Descendants("dns").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value") != "localhost")
             .ToArray();

Comment: Nothing changed. When i step through it after the "if (!endpointsToUpdate.Any()) return;"
It skips the foreach statement, so it's almost as if because the first folder has localhost inside it's config file. The code reads it as there's nothing to update, so it just ends the program

Comment: All your samples have localhost so it return nothing.  Change localhost to something else in your sample.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the dns value, the dns value should always be local host. I'm trying to update the endpoint address to newIPAdress if it has an actual IP address like "net.tcp://10.249.30.4:7732, but if it has net.tcp://localhost:7732/ then it should be left alone. I think I may have gave you a misunderstanding, I apologize

Comment: I was trying to following your code in yellow above and it was testing for != "localhost".  So my code gives Elements that do not contain localhost.

Comment: I realized that, which is why I wanted to clarify how would I give elements that contain IP addresses for example(net.tcp://10.249.30.4). I'm trying to update the old IP address to newIpAddress. But if an address has a localhost then should be left alone.

Comment: I added a new answer below

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a regex to only match strings that don't contain a certain string (i.e. localhost)? So if the string doesn't contain localhost do the Replace, otherwise skip the Replace. Or vice-versa, however you choose to look at it.

^(?!.*DontMatchThis).*$

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the first character of the pattern to \d (a digit) will solve issue :

```
           string newIP = "10.36.31.4";

            string addr1 = "net.tcp://localhost:7732/AuthenticationServices/Secure";
            string addr2 = "net.tcp://10.249.30.4:7732/EventSubscriberServices/Secure";

            string pattern = "//\\d[^:]+";

            string newaddr1 = Regex.Replace(addr1, pattern, "//" + newIP);
            string newaddr2 = Regex.Replace(addr2, pattern, "//" + newIP);
```

Comment: My files are still not updating. I'm sure it may be that the path is not being targeted

Comment: Check the date of the files to determine if they were saved.  The WHERE is not needed.  The Regex change will take its place.

Comment: I am which is why I know that what's happening is that it's only going through the first folder inside @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Stuff\Noodles" but not the rest. There's 10 different folders inside this directory but it's stopping at the first.

Comment: Now we know what is happening.  You are getting an exception when processing one of the files and as soon as the exception occurs you are exiting the for loop.    Adding an exception handler inside the for loop will allow the code to continue and process the rest of the files.  You then should go back and find out why at least one of the files is causing an exception.  It is possible it has credentials that do not allow the file to either be read or written.  It could be another application is locking the file.

Comment: I made edits to my post please check it out, I figured it out. I had a "return" in the middle of my foreach loop. I commented it the statement out and replaced it with a positive if statement. So it says if there is an endpoint to update then update it then continue through enumeration if not then continue through enumeration. My question is now what would I put in the else statement to continue the enumeration within the directory?

Comment: Your code is too complicated.  There is no need for the if statement.  If you got no results than you will no enter the for loop.  In this case I usually create a variable called CHANGE initially with a value of FALSE.  Then if the REGEX finds a IP to change you set CHANGE = TRUE.  Then only save when CHANGE == TRUE.